# Pressing a button to cycle through a range's values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to create a button to automatically fill in cell `B5` with information from another sheet's cells `A1:A10`.

When the button is pressed I want `B5` to contain the info from cell `A1`. Then, when the button is pressed again, it should contain the info from `A2` and so on.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Here is short simple method.

You will need a counter to increment with each button press. You will need to put this somewhere on your spreadsheet, for this example it's below the button.

1. First Decide where your counter will go, for this example it will be directly below the button.

[image: Counter will increment]

2. Insert your Button.

[image: Insert Button (Form Control)]

3. Assign Macro to your Button, make sure you save it to the workbook.

[image: Assign Macro]

4. Paste below code into VBA Editor for your Button Click.

**Code**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim CopySheet As Worksheet, PasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim xFrom As Integer, xTo As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim pasteCell As String, cCell As String

    'Sheets
    Set CopySheet = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Sheet you are copying from.
    Set PasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")  'Sheet you are pasting into.

    'Rows, range of rows start from row rStart to rEnd
    rStart = 1 'Start of Row you want to copy from.
    rEnd = 10 'End of Row you want to copy from.

    'Cells
    pasteCell = "B5" 'Cell we will paste data from CopySheet.

    'Counter will increments with each button press.
    cCell = "E5" 'Change "E5" to reference cell on your spreadsheet.
    i = Range(cCell).Value

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'We disable Screen Updating to prevent interruption.

    'Update Counter
    i = i + 1
    If (i > rEnd) Then
        i = rStart
    End If
    Range(cCell).Value = i

    'Copy/Paste Functions
    CopySheet.Select
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    PasteSheet.Select
    Range(pasteCell).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Enable Screen Updating at end of operation.
End Sub
```

[image: VBA Editor]

The button will copy based on the counter number plus 1, so if the number is 0 on button press the macro will add get the 0 + 1 then begin the copy and paste functions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to store a counter in a cell in the workbook. You can use a static variable instead.

Paste the following code into any non-class module:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <any non-class module>
' Version    : 0.1.1
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1331173/763880
'============================================================================================

Option Explicit

Public Sub Next_Click()

  Const s_DestSheet As String = "Sheet1"
  Const s_DestRange As String = "B5"
  Const s_SrcSheet As String = "Sheet2"
  Const s_SrcCell As String = "A1:A10"

  Static sidxCurrentCell As Variant: If IsEmpty(sidxCurrentCell) Then sidxCurrentCell = -1

  With Worksheets(s_SrcSheet).Range(s_SrcCell)
    sidxCurrentCell = (sidxCurrentCell + 1) Mod .Cells.Count
    .Cells(sidxCurrentCell + 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(s_DestSheet).Range(s_DestRange)
  End With

End Sub
```

Then assign it to your button.

The only issue with this code is that it doesn't remember which cell it was up to when you re-open the workbook, and restarts from the first cell. This can be worked around if desired.

---

**Addendum:**

If you also wish to have a "Previous" button to cycle backwards, it gets slightly trickier - you need a generalised Previous/Next subroutine with a parameter to determine the direction. Then, each button needs to be assigned to separate subroutines that call the main routine with the appropriate argument:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <any non-class module>
' Version    : 0.2.0
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1331173/763880
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Private Sub Next_or_Previous( _
                                       ByRef direction As Long _
                            )
        Dim plngDirection As Long: plngDirection = direction

  Const s_DestSheet As String = "Sheet1"
  Const s_DestRange As String = "B5"
  Const s_SrcSheet As String = "Sheet2"
  Const s_SrcCell As String = "A1:A10"

  Static sidxCurrentCell As Variant: If IsEmpty(sidxCurrentCell) Then sidxCurrentCell = -plngDirection

  With Worksheets(s_SrcSheet).Range(s_SrcCell)
    sidxCurrentCell = (sidxCurrentCell + plngDirection + .Cells.Count) Mod .Cells.Count
    .Cells(sidxCurrentCell + 1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(s_DestSheet).Range(s_DestRange)
  End With

End Sub

Public Sub Previous_Click()
  Next_or_Previous -1
End Sub

Public Sub Next_Click()
  Next_or_Previous 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

**My approach is quit different to solve the issue.**

*I would like to suggest **Worksheet Selection Change Event** instead of **Button Click** , since it avoids the tedious **Loop method task***.

***Worksheet Selection Change*** almost works like **Button Click**, since for 10 items 10 Clicks are required, as well as **Selection Change Event** also needs similar Clicks, and the best part is the order, it could be Ascending/Descending or even Random.

*Below written code will copy cells from designated Data Range `A1:A10` on Mouse Click, to destination Sheet's Cell.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A10")) Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Select
        .Range("B5").Value = Target.Value
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

**How the Macro works:**

- Click any Cell between `A1:A10` at **Source Sheet** to Copy to **Destination Sheet's Cell** `B5`.

**Note,** Source Range `A1:A10`, destination Sheet's name `Sheet2` & Cell `B5` are editable.

Comment: Write your concern to Down vote the post !!

Comment: Your post does not provide a solution to the OP. And responding to an old question that shows no effort is not good either.

Comment: @AJD,, did you ever tried the Code I've posted, and find the Text on the TOP of my answer, I've mentioned that my approach is different and after that I've explained the reason behind opting the different approach!! Don't you think that a problem could have many Solutions and the way to solve also may different !!

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a button press which indicates a particular user exchange with the application. A selection change is a different action. Having said that, this is a very poor question with no attempts at a solution in the first place and shouldn't have been answered (the O is seeking a code writing service)..

Comment: @ADJ,, `Worksheet Selection Change` exactly works like Button Click, for both Mouse Click is essential so that I've suggested this one. Both Codes placing data in Cell and mine has enough liberty,, it may be Sequential or Random even.

Comment: You are thinking like a coder, not a user. Yes, the underlying code is the same, but the user experience is different. The OP asks for a function that cycles on the click of a button, not a function that adapts to where the user clicks on the sheet.